Mercurial Hg Python openssl library won't connect to Apache v2 default SSL setup
I'm trying to run hg pull --insecure on a Mac OS X laptop against Mercurial's hgweb running on an Apache v2 webserver.
I receive the command line error:
abort: could not set ciphers: No cipher can be selected.
(change cipher string (DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0) in config)

My Mercurial (hg) version is: 6.8.1 built from a *.tar.gz "tarball" from the SCM website.  The repository folder I'm pulling into is copied verbatim from a win32 machine running TortoiseHg.  Python version is Python 3.9.6.
My Apache version is: Server version: Apache/2.4.62 (Debian)  The connection is over SSL.  I believe my TLS support is "nearly default" in the Apache configuration with a self-signed certificate.
When I connect to Apache via FireFox, FireFox reports TLS 1.3 in the security settings.  However, I know Python openssl as run in my Mercurial scripts is configured to only support TLS 1.2.  (I see this in the file sslutil.py in the mercurial-6.8.1.tar.gz archive)
I am able to run Mercurial hg commands successfully using TortoiseHg on several MS Windows machines against the same hgweb webserver.
How can I get this working?  Why isn't python able to negotiate a TLS 1.2 session with my Apache webserver?
